# TRect.Intersect and TRect.IntersectsWith Inconsistencies

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

I am hoping that I am confused in some way. I am getting some inconsistent behavior with `TRect.Intersect` and `TRect.IntersectsWith`. Here is some code that demonstrates the problem.

```
program RectCheck;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Types,
  Vcl.Dialogs;

var
  rect1: TRect;
  rect2: TRect;
  combinedRect: TRect;
begin
  Rect1 := Rect(0,0,200,101);
  Rect2 := Rect(0,100,200,200);
  if Rect1.IntersectsWith(Rect2) then
  begin
    // We have interesected, get the combined rect
    combinedRect := TRect.Intersect(Rect1, Rect2);
    if not combinedRect.IsEmpty then
      ShowMessage(Format('Our new rect (%d, %d), (%d, %d)',
          [combinedRect.Left, combinedRect.Top, combinedRect.Right, combinedRect.Bottom]))
    else
      raise Exception.Create('They were supposed to intersect!');
  end;

  Rect1 := Rect(0,0,200,100);
  Rect2 := Rect(0,100,200,200);
  if Rect1.IntersectsWith(Rect2) then
  begin
    // We have interesected, get the combined rect
    combinedRect := TRect.Intersect(Rect1, Rect2);

    if not combinedRect.IsEmpty then
      ShowMessage(Format('Our new rect (%d, %d), (%d, %d)',
          [combinedRect.Left, combinedRect.Top, combinedRect.Right, combinedRect.Bottom]))
    else
      raise Exception.Create('They were supposed to intersect!');
  end;
end.
```

The second exception is raised. `TRect.IntersectsWith` indicates that the rects intersect but when I call `TRect.Intersect` to get the new intersected rect then it returns an empty rect.

The code in IntersectsWith (which isn't written very clearly) is returning true in the second case because Self.BottomRight.Y = R.TopLeft.Y (100).

```
function TRect.IntersectsWith(const R: TRect): Boolean;
begin
  Result := not ( (Self.BottomRight.X < R.TopLeft.X) or
                  (Self.BottomRight.Y < R.TopLeft.Y) or
                  (R.BottomRight.X < Self.TopLeft.X) or
                  (R.BottomRight.Y < Self.TopLeft.Y) );
end;
```

The problem is that `IsRectEmpty` which is called by `Intersect` checks to see if either the top and bottom of the rect or the left and right of the rect have the same values and when that passes `Intersect` sets the result to an empty rect.

```
function IsRectEmpty(const Rect: TRect): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (Rect.Right <= Rect.Left) or (Rect.Bottom <= Rect.Top);
end;
```

Is this the expected behavior and if not what should be changed. My understanding is that TRects exclude the bottom and right "edges" and if that's the case shouldn't `TRect.IntersectsWith` look something like this?

```
function TRect.IntersectsWith(const R: TRect): Boolean;
begin
  Result := not ( (Self.BottomRight.X <= R.TopLeft.X) or
                  (Self.BottomRight.Y <= R.TopLeft.Y) or
                  (R.BottomRight.X <= Self.TopLeft.X) or
                  (R.BottomRight.Y <= Self.TopLeft.Y) );
end;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a bug; this cannot be the expected behavior. In the current implementation, RTL thinks two empty rects can intersect (e.g. `(0,0,0,0)`, `(0,0,0,0)`, or one non-empty rect with an empty one), which does not make any sense.

```
Assert(Rect(0, 0, 0, 0).IntersectsWith(Rect(0, 0, 0, 0)));
```

The above assertion does not fail.

Also, it does not work in accordance with the Windows api. The below assertion fails: winapi thinks `(0,0,200,100)` and `(0,100,200,200)` do not intersect.

```
Assert(winapi.windows.IntersectRect(OutRect, Rect(0,0,200,100), Rect(0,100,200,200)));
```

The overload of `System.Types.IntersectRect()` that returns a boolean is equally broken.

Comment: Thanks, I have added a QC with some of your info (http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=127696)

Comment: Hmmm... Two empty recs are identical, so of course they intersect, IMO. The intersection is, of course, the empty rect. But `Rect(0, 0, 100, 200)` and `Rect(0, 100, 200, 200)` should not intersect, IMO, even if they, nominally, have the point `(0, 100)` in common (but not in reality, since that point is, in Windows, not part of the first rect).

Comment: @Rudy - An empty rect is a rect that isn't. It cannot intersect with anything, it doesn't even have an interior/area.

Comment: An empty rect is a TRect with values `(0, 0, 0, 0)`. It is still a TRect. And identical rects always intersect, IMO.

Comment: @Rudy - Have a test with `winapi.Windows.IntersectRect(OutRect, Rect(0, 0, 10, 10), Rect(5, 5, 5, 5))` to see if they intersect. But your intersection definition might be different than mine, or the OS'. That wouldn't be relevant for the purposes of this question though.

Comment: It is a philosophical matter, I guess. In some languages, the equivalent of `Pos('', 'ABC')` returns the equivalent of `<not_found>`, in some it returns `<first_position>`.

Comment: @Rudy - FWIW I don't disagree (0, 0, 0, 0) is a TRect, I disagree it is a rectangle.